# .Net MVC deploy a dacpac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dacpac

I'm trying to do deploy dacpac. I'm having errors though when running below code.

```
            var dacpacName = "Setup.dacpac";
            var dacpacPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/dacpac"), dacpacName);

            var dp = DacPackage.Load(dacpacPath);
            var dbDeployOptions = new DacDeployOptions
            {
                BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = false,
                ScriptDatabaseOptions = false,
                GenerateSmartDefaults = true,
                CreateNewDatabase = true
            };
```

When running the code I'm encountering the error:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage' threw an exception.
```

This happens just right after the:

```
 var dp = DacPackage.Load(dacpacPath);
```

My path is:

```
var dacpacPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/dacpac"), dacpacName);
```

So the path is pointing to the exact location of the dacpac file but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ced08955-1d00-48cd-a3fc-905e4fd07f43/error-installing-dacpac-using-sqlpackageexe?forum=ssdt

I search the ff from nuget and installed it, and the error is gone.

- T-SQL ScriptDom
- SQLSysCLRTypes

Thanks,